# How to show videos in Visual Studio Android Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

I have a video view in my project that plays videos . when I use Visual Studio Android Emulator, it only shows a black screen and i can hear the audio . 
So what is the way to show these videos ? It is worth to mention that other emulators play video with almost no issue .